# Changing the dismiss animation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So my code is incredibly straight forward right now

```
    - (IBAction)goHome:(id)sender {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        //transition changer here?       
    }
```

All I want to do is use the flip-horizontal transition rather than use the same transition (dissolve)?

Probably really simple, but I can't find an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

When moving into a view controller.

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:toViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When dismissing a viewController.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so the first section of code, does this need to go into the view controller I'm switching to or the one I'm switching from?

Comment: @GlenRitchie  First section of code goes into the view controller your switching from. And the second is the view controller from where your switching back.

Comment: @DuncanC , thanks, I intended to be a little more generic , but this is better.

Comment: Still not quite getting this, could you try and explain a bit further? (Total noob.)